# Describe the main methods associated with the Queue abstract data type and discuss their relationship with the stack data structure

Tags: data-structures, methods, stack, queue

I am studying for an exam and I'm a bit confused as to how to answer this question.The way I interpret it is that they want to know the methods of stack which are,`offer` `peek` `poll` `size` `isEmpty` and their functons which I understand.But the part I'm stuck at is describing there relationship with the stack.I know the stack methods `empty`,`peek` and `pop` are similar but is this the correct way to answer this question?Thanks

Comment: is this question related to java ? if yes, are you referring to Stack class in  java.util package ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A queue is last in first out (LIFO), and a stack is first in first out (FIFO). Therefore, every method in a queue matches a parallel, but reverse method in a stack. So `offer` corresponds to `push`, and `poll` corresponds to `pop`.